# Changing the graph line's color depending on date

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I am plotting formation against dates. Is it possible to change the color of the plotted line depending on the date (which is on the axis)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Is it something like [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want. The same line having different colours. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Actually that seems overly complicated. Is there no way to just change the color depending on an input?

Answer (score 7):

You can define masks and use them to differentiate the "segments" you want for the line.

Below is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

# 4 segments defined according to some x properties
segment1 = (x<-5)
segment2 = (x>=-5) & (x<0)
segment3 = (x>=0) & (x<5)
segment4 = (x>=5)

plt.plot(x[segment1], y[segment1], '-k', lw=2)
plt.plot(x[segment2], y[segment2], '-g', lw=2)
plt.plot(x[segment3], y[segment3], '-r', lw=2)
plt.plot(x[segment4], y[segment4], '-b', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]